# How do I separate my templates correctly in Django?

Tags: django

I'm in doubt as to how I can make my templates in Django. I created three apps on my django:

1. User
2. Posts
3. Index

And each app I create a folder called "templates" and there I make the templates for these pages, but there is a problem! Whenever I put the same page in my view that I created in another template, all the repeated content appears there, is there any way to make this not happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Rick!  There are a few ways to configure templates in Django.  This answer is specific to defining templates within each app.  Let's take that 'Posts' app for example.

Within the posts app folder, create a `templates` folder, and then create ANOTHER folder under templates called `posts` (should match the app name).  So:

```
BASEDIR/
  > posts
    > templates
      > posts
        (store your posts templates/html files here)
        - show_post.html
        - posts.html
        etc, etc
```

Then when you call `render` in a view, it will look like:

```
def show_post(request, post_id):
  #-- your view logic here --#
  context = {'post': post }
  return render(request, 'posts/show_post.html', context)
```

The above render function will look for the template at `posts/templates/posts/show_post.html`.

For all of this to work, make sure you have APP_DIRS set to True in your settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
  { 
    'BACKEND': ...
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,   #<-- this line is key
    (etc, etc)
  }
]
```

As you add apps to your project, use the same structure as we did with Posts.  And be sure to call the correct template in `render` in your view.

Like I said, there's more than one way to organize your Django templates, but this method has worked well for me on small and medium sized Django projects.

Answer (score 1):

In your views.py render statement, you should reference the template like this:

---

### `views.py` for `Posts` App:

```
def index(request):
    # Notice that I am putting the template as "appname/template_file_name.html"
    return render(request, context={'..':...}, "posts/index.html")
```

### Another example

### Your `views.py` for `Users` App

```
def login(request):
     return render(request, context, "users/login.html")
```

And it is as easy as that!